# msqldump without shell interpretation

Tags: java, shell, mysql

I am trying to run a command on a remote server via a java program. Part of the code is below:

```
Process backUp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(backUp.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(backUp.getErrorStream()));
```

with the cmd string containing:

```
 sudo mysqldump --host=localhost --no-data --user=root --password=*******
 lbs company > /home/ubuntu/michael/***************/lbs.company.sql
```

I know my problem here is that the ">" is used for shell-interpreted commands which don't work with runtime.exec. How can I format my mysqldump command to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: any reason you're running this via sudo? mysqldump doesn't need root rights, and you don't have to **BE** system root to be able to log in as the mysql root user. the names may be the same, but mysql accounts and system accounts are completely unrelated.

Comment: Thank you. You're right I don't need to. It runs either way though. I'm mostly worried about how to specify which folder to output to without using ">"

Comment: have you tried specifying the output via [--result-file](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html)?

Comment: Thats it tim! Thank you

Comment: sure thing. I added it as a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the output via ">", you can use [--result-file](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html) to specify the output of mysqldump. So

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=******* lbs company > /home/lbs.company.sql
```

becomes

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=******* --result-file=/home/lbs.company.sql lbs company
```